# What is the correct way to use the redis cache inside an Apollo DataSource class

Tags: apollo-server

I have the following class method :

```
async order(id,{ttlInSeconds}={}){
            const cachedOrder=await this.cache.get(this.cacheKey(id))

            if (cachedOrder){
                return JSON.parse(cachedOrder)
            }

            const order=await this.models.Order.findOne({
                where:{
                    id:id
                }
            })

            if(ttlInSeconds){
                await this.cache.set(this.cacheKey(id),JSON.stringify(order),{ttl:ttlInSeconds})
            }

            return order
        }
```

But it never gets resolved , what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have encountered this problem when extending Apollo's DataSource class too. I have no idea why , but you should not await for the cache to set the value, even tough in the spec **it does** await for the value (https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/blob/0aa0e4b20ef97576ce92733698a7842b61d8280e/packages/apollo-server-caching/src/KeyValueCache.ts#L10-L14). As a result , try this :

```
async order(id,{ttlInSeconds}={}){
            const cachedOrder=await this.cache.get(this.cacheKey(id))

            if (cachedOrder){
                return JSON.parse(cachedOrder)
            }

            const order=await this.models.Order.findOne({
                where:{
                    id:id
                }
            })

            if(ttlInSeconds){
                this.cache.set(this.cacheKey(id),JSON.stringify(order),{ttl:ttlInSeconds})
            }

            return order
        }
```